# Handle Scala Option idiomatically

Tags: scala, scala-option

What is the more idiomatic way to handle an `Option`, `map` / `getOrElse`, or `match`?

```
val x = option map {
  value => Math.cos(value) + Math.sin(value)
} getOrElse {
  .5
}
```

or

```
val x = option match {
    case Some(value) => Math.cos(value) + Math.sin(value)
    case None => .5
}
```

Comment: This question should not be closed for being primarily opinion based. Coming from Python, I know there are hundreds of questions on SO about the most "Pythonic" (idiomatic) ways to do this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could always just look at the [Scaladoc for Option](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.1/scala/Option.html):

*The most idiomatic way to use an scala.Option instance is to treat it as a collection or monad and use map,flatMap, filter, or foreach:*

```
val name: Option[String] = request getParameter "name"
val upper = name map { _.trim } filter { _.length != 0 } map { _.toUpperCase }
println(upper getOrElse "")
```

And a bit later:

*A less-idiomatic way to use scala.Option values is via pattern matching:*

```
val nameMaybe = request getParameter "name"
nameMaybe match {
  case Some(name) =>
    println(name.trim.toUppercase)
  case None =>
    println("No name value")
}
```

Comment: I would not and do not object to that, but do note that `match` constructs compile to inline code. HOFs require first-class functions and those functions each generate a class to capture their bodies and must be instantiated each time they're used. So in those situations where overhead matters (the proverbial inner loop), the match might be called for. Also, I think most people find them more readily graspable than a HOF *when applicable*, which more or less means when their used in isolation. In a monadic chain where you'd use for comprehension, it's simply the only way.

Comment: Interesting...they didn't mention fold

Comment: The opportunity to use `fold` didn't arrive Scala 2.10. Also, people will often differ on the readability of `fold` vs. `map().getOrElse()`. But I would say both are idiomatic, and both are more idiomatic than `match`.

Answer (score 4):

Use `fold` for this kind of map-or-else-default thing:

```
val x = option.fold(0.5){ value => Math.cos(value) + Math.sin(value) }
```

Comment: although it does answer the question from the 'idiomatic' perspective, the catamorphism on Option is hard to read. A -1 from code maintainability POV. See this discussion & conclusion on the topic: http://apache-spark-developers-list.1001551.n3.nabble.com/Option-folding-idiom-td25.html

Comment: The argument order of `fold` seems to be a sticking point in that discussion; it might be worth noting that Scalaz proves a `.cata` extension method with the expected argument order: `option.cata(value => cos(value) + sin(value), 0.5)`. By having a single parameter list it also avoids the usual hiccups with too-specific inferred types breaking stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously both are valid and I don't think one is more idiomatic than the other.  That being said, using map uses the fact the Option is a Monad.  This can be particularly advantageous when combining two Options.  Say you have two Option[Int] that you would like to add.  In this case instead of doing multiple matches it is much cleaner to use map/flatMap and it's equivalent "for comprehensions".  So for your example both are valid... but for other examples using map/flatMap is often much more succinct.

```
Some(6).flatMap(intValue => Some(5).map(intValue + _))
```

or

```
for {
   i <- Some(6)
   j <- Some(5)
} yield i + j
```

Answer (score 0):

All of them have different semantics, so in your case none of them.

`map` applies some function to the value inside `Option`, if it exists (`Some`, not `None`). Basically this is how you safely work with `Options`, appling function on some `null` value is dangeroues, cause it can throw NPE, but in case with Option it just returns None.

`getOrElse` simply returns either it's value or default one (which you provide as an argument). It won't do anything with the value inside the `Option`, you can just extract it, if you have `Some`, or return a default one, in case of None.

and `match` approach i'd say is a combination of two, cause you can apply some computation on the values and extract it from the `Option`